# Override <title>TITLE</title> through Header

Tags: javascript, string, overriding

Is there a way I could override the title of my page, which I cannot edit directly, only adding Javascript in the header?

The line I cannot directly edit is:

```
<title>Title of the page</title>
```

The only way I can imagine solving this is inserting a Javascript command in the Header file that I can upload through the backend of my portal. This, I've been told, accepts Javascript.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `document.title`:

```
document.title = "This Is A New Title!";
```

You can put that in a `<script>` tag just about anywhere.